# Can't share open graph with Android Facebook SDK 4

Tags: android, facebook-opengraph

Code:

```
String imgURL = mShareParams.getImageURL();
imgURL = imgURL.substring(0, imgURL.lastIndexOf("/"));
ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder().putString("og:type", "article").putString("fb:app_id",mContext.getString(R.string.facebook_app_id)).putString("og:url", mShareParams.getUrl()).putString("og:title", mShareParams.getContentTitle()).putString("og:image", imgURL).putString("og:image:type", "png").build();
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder().setActionType("og.likes").putObject("article", object).build();
ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()        .setPreviewPropertyName("article").setAction(action).build();
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareDialog.show((Activity)mContext, content);
}
```

Result:

> Action Requires At Least One Reference:The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects.At least one of the following properties must be specified:object.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the action type `og.likes`. You should change it to:

`news.publishes` or `news.reads`